# Limit the number of parallel processing of a servlet

Tags: weblogic

We have a servlet which occupies more virtual memory on the server as it downloads files . For this reason, we would like to limit the concurrent requests to this server say for example we would only want 10 requests processed in parallel. We would want other requests  wait in the queue.

Can a custom thread pool be created, and configured to define max number of threads and assign for this servlet to handle this scenario? We are using WebLogic server 9.2. Or is there any other better approach to do this? Appreciate any thoughts.

Could we configure a separate servlet and configure the thread pool to only allow X number of concurrent requests, all other requests would be placed in queue to use the next available servlet. Does this approach throw a timeout error? Can you please share more details around this? Thanks

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222%5F01/wls/docs92/perform/appb%5Fqueues.html

Comment: You may want to explain how this is different than your question from yesterday before it gets closed.

Comment: Don't hesitate to upvote my answer too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a custom thread pool be created and assign for this servlet to handle this scenario? We are using WebLogic server 9.2. Or is there any other better approach to do this? Appreciate any thoughts.

Yes, this is possible. Instead of using the [default self-tuning work manager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1067159) (starting with Weblogic 9.x, execute queues are replaced by work managers for thread pools<sup>1</sup>), you could create a work manager with specific [constraints](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1064810) like the `max-threads-constraint` and possibly the `capacity`. You can then assign a Servlet to a specific work manager using the [wl-dispatch-policy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#wp1073535) of the `weblogic.xml` deployment descriptor file.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that it's still possible to [enable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1070890) WebLogic 8.1 Thread Pool Model and to use Execute Queues.

Comment: Thanks for the above description and confirmation.